# PHP count one before last container

Tags: php

I have function that insert php code (in this case wordpress shortcode) after fourth h2 selector. Is it possible to instert code to one before last h2?

```
function wpse_ad_content_two($content)
{

    if (!is_single()) return $content;
    $paragraphAfter = 4; //Enter number of paragraphs to display ad after.
    $content = explode("<h2>", $content);
    $new_content = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($content); $i++) {
        if ($i == $paragraphAfter) {
            $new_content.= '[irp]';
        }

        $new_content.= "<h2>" . $content[$i];
    }

    return $new_content;
}
```

Comment: If you are processing valid html mark up, you can use DomDocument and/or Xpath for this.  It would be helpful if you would supply some sample input and your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I've understood what you want to achieve. If I understood good, you need to add `[irp]` in several places. In this case both before the 4th and the last `h2`.

Try this:

```
$counter = count($content);
$paragraphAfter = [4, ($counter - 2)];
$content = explode("<h2>", $content);
$new_content = '';

for ($i = 0; $i < $counter; $i++) {
    if (in_array($i, $paragraphAfter)) {
        $new_content.= '[irp]';
    }

    $new_content.= "<h2>" . $content[$i];
}

return $new_content;
```

This way, you can add to the array all the places where you want to add the `[irp]` code

Answer (score 0):

Chopping at valid html with array functions is not my preferred method, but this will work to splice-in your new element as the second last element. [array_splice()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) allows you to specify where you wish to inject a new element.  Using `0` as the 3rd parameter means: don't remove any elements in the process.

Code ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5ZgSb))

```
/* test 1 */
$content = '<h2>A</h2>
<h2>B</h2>
<h2>C</h2>
<h2>D</h2>
<h2>E</h2>';
/* test 2
$content = '<h2>A</h2>
';
*/
$h2s = explode("</h2>", $content);
array_splice($h2s, -2, 0, ["\n<h2>[irp]"]);
echo implode('</h2>', $h2s);
```

Output:

```
<h2>A</h2>
<h2>B</h2>
<h2>C</h2>
<h2>D</h2>
<h2>[irp]</h2>
<h2>E</h2>
```

If my fabricated data doesn't suitably represent your actual input data, please clarify your question.

---

If your `<h2>` tags have a parent element and you are working with valid html, then domdocument is a good recommendation.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/PkEjK))

```
$content = '<body>
<h2>A</h2>
<h2>B</h2>
<h2>C</h2>
<h2>D</h2>
<h2>E</h2>
</body>';

$dom = new DOMDocument; 
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);  // omit unwanted doctype/html tags
$H2s = $dom->getElementsByTagName('h2');  // target the h2 tags
$lastH2 = $H2s[$H2s->length - 1];         // isolate last h2 tag

$newnode = $dom->createElement('h2');     // create new h2 tag
$newnode->nodeValue = "[irp]";            // fill new h2 tag with desired text
$lastH2->parentNode->insertBefore($newnode, $lastH2);  // insert new h2 just before final h2
echo $dom->saveHTML();                    // display the updated $content string
```

Output:

```
<body>
<h2>A</h2>
<h2>B</h2>
<h2>C</h2>
<h2>D</h2>
<h2>[irp]</h2><h2>E</h2>
</body>
```